# telegram bot загрузка изображения

Tags: python, telegram

возможно ли отправка изображения из интернета, а не заранее скачанное?

( PyTelegramBotAPI )

Что-то вроде этого, но с ссылкой на изображение.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['test'])
def welcome(message):
    photo = open('test.png', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможна.

Просто вместо пути файла вам надо передавать url:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['test'])
def welcome(message):
    photo = "_url"
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
```